# Redefining an SDP problem

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I want to solve a Semidefinite Programming (SDP) problem with the solver *[mosek](https://mosek.com)*. The optimization problem is given by

> $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         \min\limits_{\mathbf{X},\mathbf{x}} & \text{tr}(\mathbf{AX}) + \mathbf{b}^{\top}\mathbf{x} \\
>         s.t & \begin{bmatrix}
>         \mathbf{X} & \mathbf{x}\\
>         \mathbf{x}^{\top} & 1 \\
>         \end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathbf{0}.& \\
>         \end{matrix} \tag{1}
> $$

However, mosek can solve an SDP problem in the form

> $$ \begin{matrix}
>         \min\limits_{\mathbf{Y},\mathbf{y}} & \text{tr}(\mathbf{Q}_0\mathbf{Y}) + \mathbf{c}_{0}^{\top}\mathbf{y} \\
>         s.t & \text{tr}(\mathbf{Q}_i\mathbf{Y}) + \mathbf{c}_i^{\top}\mathbf{y} \leq u_i, & i=1,2,\ldots\\ 
>         &\mathbf{Y} \succeq \mathbf{0}.& \\
>         \end{matrix} \tag{2}
> $$

I am wondering whether it is possible to write Problem $(1)$ in the form $(2)$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The key is to define $Y=\begin{bmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and let $y$ be empty. From there, you can say, for instance, $Q_0=\begin{bmatrix} A & b/2 \\ b^T/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. You'll need to set that bottom-right entry of $Y$ to equal $1$, which you can do with two opposite inequalities, although MOSEK allows mixtures of equality and inequality constraints, so I doubt that is necessary.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Thanks for your comment. :)